# Firefox: Cannot display character in input field but can display it within <p>

Tags: firefox, unicode

Firefox can display the following character in div but cannot display it in input.

龗    滙 羣 邨 埗    衞

Comment: Tested that the font must set as HKSCS for that content language in order for showing the character properly

Comment: However, I found that these characters cannot be showed properly in Chrome. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser shoule be able to display HKSCS if the Font set as 細明體_HKSCS, MingLiu_HKSCS, PMingLiU or MingLiU.

I tested in Firefox, Internet explorer and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here. First, Firefox (like browsers in general) uses a specific default font for `input` element (though this font depends on user settings). That font may well lack glyphs for some characters that are present in the font used for normal text (whether as per browser defaults or as per your CSS settings). This can be handled by setting the `font-family` for `input` elements suitably. To set it the same as the normal text font, you can use the following CSS rule:

```
input { font-family: inherit }
```

Second, your data contains [Private Use](http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html) code points such as U+F5D0. They have absolutely no meaning outside of private agreements on their use. In HTML, they are typically used in conjunction with privately-encoded “icon fonts” that have fancy icons placed in those code points, though they might also be used e.g. for rare Chinese characters (typically occurring in proper names only) that have not (yet) been encoded as characters in Unicode.

This means that such a specific font must be used to make any sense of the content. To make things work across devices, this should be a downloadable font specified with `@font-face`. If you have done that, simply declare that same font for `input` elements in CSS.